# Django reverse lookup by ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, model, django-queryset

I have a django project which has two apps, one is `AppA` and `AppB`. Now `AppA` has a model
`ModelA` which is referenced by the model `ModelB` in `AppB`, using `modelA = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, related_name='tricky')`

Now in my view for `AppA`, when it shows `ModelA`, I do a `get_object_or_404(ModelA, pk=prim_id)`. Then I want to get all the `ModelB`s which have a Foreign Key pointing to `ModelA`.

Documentation says I should do a `mb = ModelB.objects.get(pk=prim_id)` then `mb.modela_set.all()`

But, it failed on the `mb.modela_set`, and it says `"ModelB object has no attribute 'suchsuch'"`. Notice I added the `related_name` field to ForeignKey, so I tried with that as well, including `mb.tricky.all()` and `mb.tricky_set.all()` to no avail.

Oh, and I have specified a different manager for `AppA` where I do `objects = MyManager()` which returns the normal query but with a filter applied.

What could be the problem? What is the prefered way to get the `ModelB`s referencing `ModelA`?

Comment: Ah, I messed up, should have called ModelA.tricky.all() to get the modelbs refering to ModelA ... instead of what i had was ModelB.tricky.all() Gah.

Comment: If you think you described your question wrong please edit it to be right. You may also include yourmanager code!

Comment: @lazerscience, Nah I described it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `ForeignKey` is, as you describe in `ModelB` and you do `mb = ModelB.objects.get(pk=prim_id)` then the look up for the `modela` attribute **is not a reverse lookup**. you simply access the related object via `mb.modela`!

Comment: Yes, but I was trying to do ModelB.modela_set.all() to get the referenses of modelB to modelA. I didnt pay attention in the documentation at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/ (making reverse queries) that ModelA (Blog in the doc) didnt have a ForeignKey field to another model. Rather it is ModelA (Blog) which has a FOO_set.all() of all references from another model into it. Ill accept your answer because it is still correct and for others to find.